# How to load a database to struct in c++?

Tags: c++, database, struct

I have database in books.txt. The data is separated by semicolons in this way:

> id;year;author
> 1;2012;John Snow 
> 2;2011;Rihanna 
> 3;1902;Shawn Mendes
> 4;2000;Boleslaw Chrobry
> 5;2001;Papa Loui
> 6;1905;Spongebob

My code doesn't work. How can I implement this correctly? 
code:

```
struct Books
{
    std::string id; 
    std::string year;
    std::string author;

Books loading(std::string file)
{
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open(file);
    Books a[7];
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        getline(fin,a[i].id,';');
        getline(fin,a[i].year,';');
        getline(fin,a[i].author);
    }
    fin.close();
    return a[7];
}};

int main()
{
    Books books[7];
    books->loading("books.txt");
    for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
        std::cout<<books[i].author; // I don't want headline, that's why I count from 1
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Comment: Your real name is showing in the screenshot; might want to delete it, if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make the function `loading` static because it won't require access to member variables.
- Return the whole array (you should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of arrays) instead of the out-of-range thing `a[7]`
- Assign the returned thing in the caller.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct Books
{
    std::string id; 
    std::string year;
    std::string author;

static std::vector<Books> loading(std::string file)
{
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open(file);
    std::vector<Books> a(7);
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        getline(fin,a[i].id,';');
        getline(fin,a[i].year,';');
        getline(fin,a[i].author);
    }
    fin.close();
    return a;
}};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Books> books = Books::loading("books.txt");
    for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
        std::cout<<books[i].author; // I don't want headline, that's why I count from 1
}
```